# How to Avoid Object ID conflicts in Versioned geodatabase

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, versioning

We have just implemented a versioned Geodatabase and our schema has few feature classes and relationship classes.

We do not Reconcile and Post to the parent ( Default) version, as we need some intermediate monthly job extraction and do not want to mix up jobs of past month.

Our concern is , since we do not Post to default on regular base, is there a chance that Object Ids be duplicated in the monthly versions as the same as Default ? In that case wont we lose features once we post to the default at the end of the month ?

Or will the Oracle/ArcSDe take care of the Object ids for all versions , so that the basetable( Default) and the delta tables( Versions) does not have features with same Object ID in a feature class ?

Comment: You should never depend on ObjectIds to uniquely identify features. They are not guaranteed to be consistent, or without gaps.

Answer (score 2):

The version IS NOT a different table. It is a version. A branch of the state tree (if you will).  ESRI knows how to manage those ids.
The A&D tables are simply edits.  They don't have as much to do with versions as you elude in your question.
However in your extraction process without using globalid there is going to be Oid duplication.
Here is the [basic help section for versions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Recommended_version_administration_workflow/003n000000z7000000/).
And the [versioning state tree information is here.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n000000w9000000)